# Complex File content search in java

Tags: java

I have a file,having the content 'HREC ZZ INCOK4 ZZ BEOINDIANEX ICES1_5P  CHCAE02 71484 20131104 1230'(first line of file ).I need to reach the  8th word, that could be  CHCAE02 or CHCAI02 (here word is  determined by space  ) and need some logic checking on it.How can I  achieve this with java .plz  help me .It is urgent.Below shown is the full file content.

```
HREC ZZ INCOK4 ZZ BEOINDIANEX ICES1_5P  CHCAE0271484201311041230
INCOK4104112013CHA Not Registered;IEC Not Registered;Invalid Bank Code;Authorised Dealer Code of IEC Not Found;Country of Destination can not be India;Wrong Port of destination:INCOK4;Wrong Port of destination:INCOK4;Wrong RITC Code For Inv./Item No:1/1;
TREC71484
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be many ways to fetch the 8th column-

1. Using String.split(String regex)

   String word = row.split("\W+")[7];
2. if column matches certain pattern like digits count and only digits then

   String regex = "[0-9]{5}"; -- matches a word between 0 and 9 and 5 length.

Answer (score 0):

Try [String.split(regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String words[] = line.split(" ");
String eightWord = words[7];
```